# Homework - Square Root Functions with Exponents

Tags: graphing-functions

I am doing square root graphs in school and on the homework, one problem was

$$f(x) = \sqrt{x^2-25}$$

I know that there is a horizontal translation of positive 25, but how would I graph the $x^2$ without making an x/y chart?

Comment: Hint : What happens for $x \lt -5$, $x \in (-5, 5)$, $x \gt 5$?

Comment: +Amzoti What do you mean?

Comment: My teacher instructed to only graph the real coordinates

Comment: Yes, I know how to just plug various x's into the functions and get the y, but what is the characteristic of an x having an exponent? For example, if x is negative, then it is a reflection over the y axis.

Comment: the parent function looks like a baseball being hit right from the origin.

Comment: You are making this way too hard on yourself http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sqrt%28x%5E2-25%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the function is defined only for $x \leq -5$ and $5 \leq x$. Also, as $x \to \pm \infty$, the $25$ term becomes insignificant and so $f(x) \to \sqrt{x^2} = |x|$ (try showing this more rigorously).

So the graph starts at $x = \pm 5$ where $f(x) = 0$ and becomes asymptotic to $|x|$ as the magnitude of $x$ increases.